# Adding a column in a data frame based on a subset of the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

let's say I have a data frame in R similar to this one:

```
setValue  <- rep(seq(0,20,10), each=3)
readValue <- rep(1:length(setValue))
df        <- data.frame(setValue, readValue)
```

Resulting in data looking like this:

```
  setValue readValue
1        0         1
2        0         2
3        0         3
4       10         4
5       10         5
6       10         6
7       20         7
8       20         8
9       20         9
```

I want to add a new column with the result of a function based on the group defined by `setValue`. I use the `median` function for that exmaple.

The result would be like this:

```
  setValue readValue  median
1        0         1       2
2        0         2       2
3        0         3       2
4       10         4       5
5       10         5       5
6       10         6       5
7       20         7       8
8       20         8       8
9       20         9       8
```

## Solution

Best I could think of is a R-yfied for-loop() using `sapply`. For each row, a `subset` of `df` is retrieved where the current `setValue` of the row equals the `setValue` of the initial data frame `df`.

```
df$median <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) {

  median( subset(df$readValue, df$setValue == df[row,]$setValue) )

})
```

### Reducing computations

To avoid subgrouping and calculating the median repeatedly each row, I can pre-calculate the median for a given `setValue` using `aggregate`:

```
df_median <- aggregate(. ~ setValue, data=df, FUN=median)
```

Resulting in a dataframe with median values in `readValue`:

Resulting in:

```
  setValue readValue
1        0         2
2       10         5
3       20         8
```

And use the pre-calculated median-values in the function instead:

```
df$median <- sapply(1:nrow(df4), function(row) {

  subset(df_median$readValue, df_median$setValue == df[row,]$setValue)

})
```

## Question

Is there a more R-ish/efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ave` from the base of R:

```
transform(df, median = ave(readValue, setValue, FUN = median))
```

or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(setValue) %>%
  mutate(median = median(readValue)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, median := median(readValue), by = setValue]
```

Output:

```
   setValue readValue median
1:        0         1      2
2:        0         2      2
3:        0         3      2
4:       10         4      5
5:       10         5      5
6:       10         6      5
7:       20         7      8
8:       20         8      8
9:       20         9      8
```